# How to catch .exe not start or fail exception MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, exception

I try to export chart images to png or pdf with the code below.(I use Asp.Net MVC, Telerik Kendo, Inskcape)

Every user needs to have installed Inkscape software on their computers to get charts exported. I mean, if user doesn't have Inkscape, user can not get image.

So i want to control if user have Inkscape or not. If there is no installed Inkscape, i want to show exception message to related View like "Please install Inkscape to your computers"

How can i do it? With try, catch? If else? I can't get the logic about what i should.

```
  private string DoExport(string svgFile, KendoChartExport.Models.ExportFormat format)
        {

            var extension = format == KendoChartExport.Models.ExportFormat.PNG ? "png" : "pdf";
            var outFile = TempFileName() + "." + extension;
            var inkscape = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            inkscape.StartInfo.FileName = INKSCAPE_PATH;
            inkscape.StartInfo.Arguments =
                String.Format("--file \"{0}\" --export-{1} \"{2}\" --export-width {3} --export-height {4}",
                              svgFile, extension, outFile, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            inkscape.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            inkscape.Start();
            inkscape.WaitForExit();

            return outFile;
        }
```

I want to someting like that:

```
   try
            {
                 inkscape.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw ViewBag.Error = "Please Install Inkscape";
            }
```

Any idea to help?

Comment: Execution is done on the web server, why client needs to install the 3rd party software?

Comment: The server has no knowledge of applications that are installed on the client. You could display a message to the users, with perhaps a "Don't show me this again" checkbox that saves the state and prevents subsequent display

Comment: i am asking as a rookie, do you mean installing inkscape.exe to web server so clients do not install it?